# Opacity increases after "animation" property

Tags: html, css, animation

I am running the following code and once the animation completes the opacity of the image changes. Till animation is going on the image looks smooth after that it changes the opacity.

please find code at following JS: https://jsfiddle.net/7fk0b788/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
<head>
<title> joe's Pizza Co.-New York's Best Pizza</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<header>
<h1>
Joe's Pizza
</h1>

</header>


<div>

<section id="feature">
</section>

<section id="home-text">
</section>

<section id="offers">
</section>



</div>
<footer>
</footer>


</div>
</body>
</html>

#container
{
background: url("Img/background.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
background-size:cover;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
position: fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
animation: fadein 4s;
filter: opacity(50%);
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add opacity:.5; to the #container. https://jsfiddle.net/hrjh1zgp/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do it:

Add `forwards` to the `animation` property as that will make sure the animation once it hits its `100%`, it will persist:

```
animation: fadein 4s forwards;
```

or by adding

```
opacity:.5;
```

[Using `forwards`](https://jsfiddle.net/7fk0b788/1/)

[Using `opacity`](https://jsfiddle.net/7fk0b788/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the opacity .5 to 1. It'll go smooth till the end. Your code snippet below

```
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```